# Which of the PoolManager and Destroy functions is faster?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pool

I've discovered that poolManager can make the game more enjoyable. I found it fascinating, so I made my own PoolManager.
On closer study, it appears to be more intricate than the Destroy function. Wouldn't managing the PoolManager this way and using Destroy() rather than erasing the instances be more practical?

I want to make a better PollManager.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PoolManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject containerPrefab;

    [SerializeField]
    PoolProfile[] new1Profile;

    static PoolProfile[] newProfile;

    private void Awake()
    {
        newProfile = new PoolProfile[new1Profile.Length];

        for(int i = 0; i<new1Profile.Length; i++)
        {
            newProfile[i] = new1Profile[i];
        }
        Init();
    }


    public void Init()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < newProfile.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject newContainer = Instantiate(containerPrefab);
            newContainer.name = newProfile[i].name;
            newProfile[i].container = newContainer;
            for (int j = 0; j < newProfile[i].defalutAmount; j++)
            {
                GameObject prefab = Instantiate(newProfile[i].prefabSet, newContainer.transform);
                prefab.transform.position = newProfile[i].defalutVector;
                prefab.transform.parent = newContainer.transform;
                prefab.SetActive(false);
                newProfile[i].inConObject.Enqueue(prefab);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void AddAmount(Queue<GameObject> set, GameObject addObject)
    {
        set.Enqueue(Instantiate(addObject));
    }

    public static GameObject PoolRequest(Queue<GameObject> set,GameObject pullObject, Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot)
    {
        if(set.Count == 0)
        {
            AddAmount(set, pullObject);
        }
        set.Peek().SetActive(true);
        set.Peek().transform.position = pos;
        set.Peek().transform.rotation = rot;

        GameObject nowpeek = set.Peek();
        set.Dequeue();
        return nowpeek;
    }



    public static GameObject PoolRequest(string objName)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<newProfile.Length; i++)
        {
            if(newProfile[i].name == objName)
            {
                return PoolRequest(newProfile[i].inConObject,newProfile[i].inConObject.Peek(), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Quaternion(0,0,0,0));
            }
        }

        return null; 
    }

    public static GameObject PoolRequest(string objName, Vector3 pos)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < newProfile.Length; i++)
        {
            if (newProfile[i].name == objName)
            {
                return PoolRequest(newProfile[i].inConObject,newProfile[i].inConObject.Peek(), pos, new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0));
            }
        }
        return null; 
    }

    public static GameObject PoolRequest(string objName, Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < newProfile.Length; i++)
        {
            if (newProfile[i].name == objName)
            {
                return PoolRequest(newProfile[i].inConObject,newProfile[i].inConObject.Peek(), pos, rot);
            }
        }
        return null; 
    }

    public static void CullObject(GameObject cullObject)
    {
        cullObject.SetActive(false);
        cullObject.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        cullObject.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < newProfile.Length; i++)
        {
            if (cullObject.transform.parent == newProfile[i].container)
            {
                newProfile[i].inConObject.Enqueue(cullObject);
            }
        }
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
struct PoolProfile
{
    [Header("Container Name")]
    public string name;
    [Header("Default Amount")]
    public int defalutAmount;
    [Header("Add Amount")]
    public int AddAmount;
    [Header("GameObject")]
    public GameObject prefabSet;
    [Header("Container")]
    [HideInInspector]
    public GameObject container;
    [Header("Default Position")]
    public Vector3 defalutVector;
    [Header("Container Object")]
    public Queue<GameObject> inConObject;
}
```

Comment: I don't get your usage of `Peek` ... why not rather do one single `var instance = set.Dequeue();` and then `instance.SetActive(true); ..... return instance;`

Answer (score 0):

Destroy is sometimes faster than pooling objects. To be precise, the creation of the first object is often the heaviest part of the process.

It is good to introduce object pooling when object generation is dragging down the overall game. a performance check is always required after introducing object pooling.

I think the fastest way is to implement it in `Stack`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Object = UnityEngine.Object;

public sealed class ObjectPool<T> : IDisposable where T : Component
{
    readonly Stack<T> _instances = new ();
    readonly int _maxObjects;
    Transform _parent;
    T _prefab;
    bool _isDisposed;

    public ObjectPool(T prefab, int maxObjects = 0)
    {
        _prefab = prefab;
        _maxObjects = maxObjects;
        _parent = new GameObject(prefab.name + "_Poo").transform;
    }

    public ObjectPool(T prefab, GameObject parent, int maxObjects = 0)
    {
        _prefab = prefab;
        _maxObjects = maxObjects;
        _parent = parent.transform;
    }

    public ObjectPool(T prefab, Transform parent, int maxObjects = 0)
    {
        _prefab = prefab;
        _maxObjects = maxObjects;
        _parent = parent;
    }

    public T Spawn()
    {
        var instance = _instances.Count > 0
                ? _instances.Pop()
                : CreateInstance();
        instance.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        return instance;
    }

    public void DeSpawn(T instance)
    {
        instance.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        if (_maxObjects > 0
            && _instances.Count >= _maxObjects)
        {
            Object.Destroy(instance.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            _instances.Push(instance);
        }
    }

    public void PreLoad(int count)
    {
        if (_maxObjects > 0)
        {
            count = Mathf.Clamp(count, 0, _maxObjects);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            DeSpawn(CreateInstance());
        }
    }
    
    T CreateInstance() => Object.Instantiate<T>(_prefab, _parent, false);

    public void ClearAll()
    {
        while (_instances is {Count: > 0})
        {
            var obj = _instances.Pop();
            if (obj != default)
            {
                Object.Destroy(obj.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }
        _isDisposed = true;
        _parent = null;
        _prefab = null;
        ClearAll();
    }
}
```

It is used as follows

```
using UnityEngine;

public sealed class BulletsSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Bullet _bulletPrefab;

    ObjectPool<Bullet> _pool;
    
    void Awake()
    {
        _pool = new ObjectPool<Bullet>(_bulletPrefab, transform);
    }

    public Bullet Spawn(Vector3 position, Vector3 rotation)
    {
        var obj = _pool.Spawn();
        obj.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(position, Quaternion.Euler(rotation));
        return obj;
    }

    public void DeSpawn(Bullet bullet) => _pool.DeSpawn(bullet);

    void OnDestroy() => _pool.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: OP already uses a `Queue` which is as fine as a stack ;)